# How to Horizontally Center an Enumeration Display

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, line

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[I.] Item 1
\item[II.] Item 2
\item[III.] Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Instead of the output being left justified, I would like to move it to the right so that it appears horizontally centered. How may I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my actual document, the enumeration item are quite brief---so there is no risk of running off the page.

Here's an answer that implements the suggestion that @Werner provided in a comment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{RomanCount}
\renewcommand\theRomanCount{\Roman{RomanCount}}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\stepcounter{RomanCount}\theRomanCount.}r}
\newenvironment{mycenter}%
   {\begin{center}
    \Huge
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{Rl}}%
   {\end{tabular}
    \end{center}}

\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around text block

\begin{document}

\begin{mycenter}
& Item 1   \\
& Item 22  \\
& Item 333
\end{mycenter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and define a `center` `align`ment, or set the label inside a center-aligned box of fixed width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.,align=left]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\makebox[2em]{\Roman*.}}]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\SetLabelAlign{center}{\hss\makebox[0pt]{#1}\hss}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.,align=center]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You'll have to accommodate for entries that might be too wide, or other overflows into the margin(s). But these parameters can all be managed using `enumitem`. See the [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) for more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but (and perhaps I was not clear in asking the question)---I would like to take the display and shift everything (as is) perhaps 200pt or so to the right so that it appears centered. In my actual document, the enumeration item are quite brief---so there is no risk of running off the page. Is there a way to shift the display, say, Xpt to the right until the display is "centered" by inspection? Thanks again.

Comment: I see your concern about item length; I didn't think of that earlier. I suppose that an enumeration with very short items may appear not centered even though it may be, according to Latex. Thanks again.

Comment: @jean-marie: You could consider a `\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{ c l } ... \end{tabular} \end{center}` approach (changing `l` to `p{<len>}` if you have a fixed-width paragraph. Such a method would not break across the page boundary. However, having a centered list probably implies that you don't care about that around the page boundary. Regardless, if you want to move everything to the right, adjust it with something like `leftmargin=200pt`.

Answer (score 0):

A pedestrian (but simple) approach:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{1.25in}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[I.] Item 1
\item[II.] Item 2
\item[III.] Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Remark: Depending upon the length of the longest entry, you may need to adjust the width of the minipage so that it accommodates the longest entry "snugly."